# How to make Perspectives in Eclipse hidden from user in Preference->perspectives as well as Open Perspectives list?

Tags: java, eclipse

We have total 11 sets of default perspectives in Eclipse. I want to hide all the default perspectives given by eclipse and add my own customized perpective. Users should get to see only one Perpespective in the list (the one created by me).

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Comment: Are you developing an Eclipse RCP application or are you trying to configure the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: You can use 'Activities' ('org.eclipse.ui.activities' extension point) to hide things.

Comment: I am trying to configure Eclipse IDE. I tried creating a plugin and then extending "org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions" and setting visible as false, but don't know if I am doing it correctly or not.